# UILocalNotification set to alert rather than banner

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I'am firing local push notifications that are appearing as banners. How can i make the notifications be displayed as alerts ? This is what im current using:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate = date;
localNotification.alertBody = @"some notice";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
[localNotification release];
```

Im aware that you can go into the phone setting and set them as an alert type but how do you specify alert by default from the application?

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Cheers